# Создание горячих клавиш в C#

Tags: c#, winforms, события, hotkeys, visual-studio-2010

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод.

Пытаюсь написать для desktop-приложения горячие клавиши.

Делаю так:
свойство

```
KeyPreview = true;
```

Это вроде должно позволить перехватывать события, связанные с клавишами.

Дальше создаю свой метод, например на KeyDown, проверяю с помощью пошаговой отладки и вижу, что в этот метод просто нет захода. Приложение никак не реагирует на нажатые клавиши. Пробовал делать методы на остальные события KeyX, все то же самое, нет захода в метод.

В чем может быть проблема?

**Добавлено.**

На пустом проекте это работает. Осталось понять, что мешает работать тут.
На форме есть:

1. UserControl
2. XAML-евский ElementHost
3. Меню типа MenuStrip
4. Задан таймер, который при запуске программы выключен.

Больше у меня мыслей нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мда. Решил свой вопрос, конечно. Но через известное место...

Как оказалось, события формы KeyUp/Down/Press и прочая не срабатывают, т.к. весь экран занят двумя XAML-евскими elementHost-ами и прочими свистелками.
 Я сделал так(просьба не смеяться :) ):

Ввел таймер, который с частотой в 0,1 секунду проверяет нажата ли какая кнопка.
Например так:

```
 private void timerMenu_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))&&Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.O))
            {
                buttonLoad_Click(sender, e);   
            }
        }
```

Но, ИМХО, это жесть. Может кто предложить лучший вариант?

Потому что сейчас сочетание всего одно. Но их будет около 20 штук(вероятно заменю там if на switch-case) и один генерал Файлюра знает, потянет ли таймер все эти проверки с такой частотой...

---

Бугага, все гениальное просто.
Это все было неправильно.

Надо было мне уточнить, что Hotkeys нужно конкретно дя MenuStrip.

А там есть такая вещь, как ShortCutKeys. Всего-то надо использовать их.

Все.

Comment: Я тоже хотел с таймером сделать, но не получилось. И твой вариант таймера тоже не получается. Пишет: имя "KeyBoard" не существует в данном контексте.

Answer (score 1):

Надо кроме

```
KeyPreview = true;
```

Сделать обработчик события

```
PreviewKeyDown
```

Например:

```
private void Form1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Так всё-таки создаёте свой метод на KeyDown или на PreviewKeyDown? Я специально создал проект и написал этот код, чтобы проверить. У меня заработало, раз причина не в этом дайте больше информации (Может там раньше что-то перехватывает?).

Comment: Проверил на PreviewKeyDown, все равно не работает.

Comment: Черт, проверил на пустом проекте, там работает... Что-то перехватывает.

Answer (score 0):

Для установки глобальных обработчиков сообщений Windows используйте `Application.AddMessageFilter`. В реализации интерфейса `IMessageFilter` посмотрите коды сообщений от клавиатуры и обрабатывайте их. Стандартные `ShortCut`'ы пунктов меню работают через это.